# Android - WebView zoom image to full width?

Tags: android, webview

When viewing an image in a WebView, is there a programmatic way to force the WebView to automatically zoom the image until it's full width in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This html code shows an image at full size:

```
<html><head></head><body><img src= "imagename.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></body></html>
```

Now create a javascript function(`showImage`) that prints this.(I don't know how to do that).

And call your javascript function like this:

```
myWebview.loadUrl("javascript:showImage("imagename.jpg")");
```

How you can call a Javascript function from android code is explained here:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/using-webviews.html